# I am unable to upgrade my mac M1 multipass instance running Focal. Somehow it wants to install a kernel from Xenial

Tags: updates, mac, multipass

I am unable to upgrade my mac M1 multipass instance. Looks like it can no longer find the sources:

```
Failed to fetch http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/by-hash/SHA256/3148af0f0133dbef92669209f1d85fdd47498ba5005080571bc515027f1a335c  404  Not Found [IP: 147.75.95.133 80]
```

I have done some digging but am unsure of exactly how to proceed.

This is a recently installed instance of multipass Ubuntu on the mac:

```
lsb_release -d 
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
```

I am not sure why the sources are pointing to an old arm64 release?

Firstly, thank you for responding. This is a recently installed instance of multipass Ubuntu on the mac:
lsb_release -d
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04) has reached end of life in April 2021, and is not anymore supported. You can upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (which will be supported until April 2025), and it should work. Alternatively, perform a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: When releases reach EOL (inc. end of *standard* support as applies with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS; only 16.04 ESM has continued support) many mirrors/archives drop support for it.  Some are fast to drop support (ie. 1 May 2021) others get around to it *later* as it can be *dropped* any time after EOL (30 April 2021) , but either way 16.04 *standard* or *public* support ended on 30 April 2021 so you're off-topic here, unless your question is specific to helping you move to a *supported* release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for responding.
This is a recently installed instance of multipass Ubuntu on the mac:
lsb_release -d
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

I am not sure why the sources are pointing to an old arm64 release?

Comment: Did you change the default repositories?

Comment: Please [edit] to post the full output of `sudo apt update`.